# How to Set formulas for a range of cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have started learning Excel more recently. I am learnng to use Excel Formulas. In Cell 
C8 I type the formula = (C8*DividedShares)/TotalShares. Divided Shares and Total Shares are named cells and I have plugged in values 12345 and TotalShares as 21000. Now I want to apply this formula from cell C9 to C1000. What is the quickest way to do it using keyboard keys.

Comment: If the formula in C8 is =(C8*DividedShares)/TotalShares, I hope you realise that it's iterative, and have the appropriate settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the formula is written, copy the cell, pressing Ctrl-C. Then you need to select the range you want to fill with the formulas (with the keyboard, keep Shift pressed and go down with the arrow key for a while). Then, without unselecting, push enter.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is quite right. Alternatively, if this was an action that had to be repeated, the process could be written in VBA and a key combination assigned to call the code.